# Need help to find where does API takes data from in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am a begginer and i work in a MVC project which I cant understand it well yet.
I can't understand where does the API takes data from when I try to connect in Login Screen.
It doesn't use Entity Framework and there isn't a json with the data.
When I enter Id and Pass it calls an API (GetAPIResponse) which somehow finds that is correct.
Need help to understand the code and the logic behind it.

LoginBL class contains:

```
 public bool IsAuthenticated(LoginEntity user)
        {
            string url = string.Empty;
            string callType = string.Empty;
            string server = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                // get URL, Call type, Server from config file
                url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["login_url"].ToString();
                callType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["calltype"].ToString();
                server = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"].ToString();

                // Encrypt password 
                string password = Scrambler.GenerateMD5Hash(user.Password);

                // Prepare content for the POST request
                string content = @"calltype=" + callType + "&server=" + server + "&user=" + user.UserName + "&pass=" + password + "";
                Debug.WriteLine("Callcenter login url: " + content);

                HttpResponseMessage json_list = ApiCallBL.GetAPIResponse(url, content);
                LoginResponseEntity obj = new LoginResponseEntity();
                obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResponseEntity>(json_list.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

                Debug.WriteLine(callType + " Response: " + json_list.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

                //if API resultCode return 0 then user details and token save in session for further use
                if (obj.ResultCode == 0)
                {
                    int restrict = obj.UserInfo.RestrictCallType.HasValue ?
                                    obj.UserInfo.RestrictCallType.Value : 0;

                    HttpContext.Current.Session["user_id"] = obj.UserInfo.usr_id;
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["user_name"] = obj.UserInfo.usr_username;
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["user_group_id"] = obj.UserInfo.UserGroupID;
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["groupid"] = obj.UserInfo.groupid;
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["token"] = obj.Token;
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["web_server_url"] = obj.ServerInfo.web_server_url;
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["centerX"] = obj.ServerInfo.DefaultGeoX;
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["centerY"] = obj.ServerInfo.DefaultGeoY;
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["dateFormat"] = obj.ServerInfo.dateFormat;
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["currency"] = obj.ServerInfo.currency;
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["customer_img"] = obj.ServerInfo.customer_img;
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["groups"] = obj.groups;
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["restrict_call_type"] = restrict ;
                    

                    

                    Debug.WriteLine("obj.UserInfo.UserGroupID " + obj.UserInfo.UserGroupID);
                    Debug.WriteLine("obj.UserInfo.groups " + obj.groups);
                    
                    //HttpContext.Current.Session["defaultLanguage"] = obj.ServerInfo.defaultLanguage;


                    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("Login");
                    
                    // if remember me checked then user name and password stored in cookie else cookes is expired 
                    if (user.RememberMe)
                    {
                        cookie.Values.Add("user_name", obj.UserInfo.usr_username);
                        cookie.Values.Add("pwd", user.Password);
                        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(15);
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //ResultCode -5 :Invalid Login ,-1:Database Error ,-2:Server Error ,-3:Invalid Parameter specified ,-4:Invalid Token  
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                url = string.Empty;
                callType = string.Empty;
                server = string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

Okay here after converts pass to MD5 creates a "string content" with the information given.
Then in next line (`HttpResponseMessage json_list = ApiCallBL.GetAPIResponse(url, content);`) calls the API with the url and content as parameters where it finds if the data exists.

API code:

```
 public static HttpResponseMessage GetAPIResponse(string url, string content)
        {
            StringBuilder traceLog = null;
            HttpContent httpContent = null;
            try
            {
                traceLog = new StringBuilder();
                traceLog.AppendLine("Start: BusinessLayer getAPIResponse() Request Data:- " + DateTime.Now + "URL = " + url + "&content = " + httpContent);
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    httpContent = new StringContent(content);
                    httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    var resp = client.PostAsync(url, httpContent).Result;

                  
                    Debug.WriteLine("resp: " + resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

                    traceLog.AppendLine("End: BusinessLayer getAPIResponse() call completed HttpResponseMessage received");
                    return resp;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                traceLog = null;
                httpContent.Dispose();
                url = string.Empty;
                content = string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

In the following line, console prints the result that I cant understand where it cames from (`Debug.WriteLine("resp: " + resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);`)

Sorry for the confusion , I am in my first job with zero work experience and I am called to learn how this works alone without proper education on ASP.NET from them.

Answer (score 1):

You will not go very far without debbugger. Learn how to debug in Visual Studio (YouTube tutorials might be fastest way). Place debug points along critical points in code (for example moment when client sends and receives response is line `var resp = client.PostAsync...`) and check variables.

Url for API server is actually defined in the line
`url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["login_url"].ToString();`
ConfigurationManager means Web.config file, check it's appSettings section for login_url entry, there is your url.

Btw, `using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())` is not a good way to use a HttpClient and will lead to port exhaustion. It's ok for small number of requests, but for larger ones you must reuse it, or use HttpClientFactory (for .NET Core).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So i am calling an API server with this url and with parameters as calltype, server, user, pass and ask this server if there is a json with those informations? In the server exists something like a database json files?

Comment: It's probably normal database tables and response is returned in json format with selected properties (API usually returns json format).